# Why does my App stuck on lunch Screen Whenever I am using AppLoading Component in expo

Tags: expo, react-native

I follow the AppLoading component installation from expo documentation but, Whenever I lunch my app on my real device in Expo go it will get stuck on the splash screen it doesn't show me any error in the console. below is my App.js file also, I have researched all the neccesary blogs and developers forums out there but still can't find a solution to this problem.

I Knew it was the AppLoading Component that is causing the problem because when I use useEffect hook the problem go away but my app performs poorly because I need to add AppLoading for better loading performances.

App.js

```
import React, {  useState } from 'react';

import { NavigationContainer, useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';


import AuthNavigator from './app/Navigation/AuthNavigator';
import navigationTheme from './app/Navigation/navigationTheme';
import AppNavigator from './app/Navigation/AppNavigator';


import OfflineNotice from './app/components/OfflineNotice';
import AuthContext from './app/auth/context';
import authStorage from './app/auth/storage';
import jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { useEffect } from 'react/cjs/react.development';


export default function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState();

  const [isReady, setIsReady] = useState(false);

  const restoreToken = async() => { 
    const token = await authStorage.getToken();
    if (!token) return;
    setUser(jwtDecode(token));
  }
  if (!isReady)
    return (
      <AppLoading startAysnc={restoreToken}
        onFinish={() => setIsReady(true)}
      />
      
    );
  
  console.log("hi");
 
  // useEffect(() => {
  //   restoreToken();  
  // },[])
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{user,setUser}}>
     <OfflineNotice /> 
    <NavigationContainer theme={navigationTheme}>
     {user ?<AppNavigator/>:<AuthNavigator/>}
    </NavigationContainer>  
    
    </AuthContext.Provider>  
  
  );

  

}
```

Comment: Have you debugged `restoreToken`? Does it get called? Does `await authStorage.getToken()` finish? What happens at `if (!token) return;`?